Angular 18 component is imported as non standalone component but fails to render
How to wire correctly NavbarComponent into the template of app component?

app.component.html
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

main.ts
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {bootstrapApplication, BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from "@angular/material/autocomplete";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from "@angular/material/button-toggle";
import {MatCardModule} from "@angular/material/card";
import {MatCheckboxModule} from "@angular/material/checkbox";
import {MatChipsModule} from "@angular/material/chips";
import {MatStepperModule} from "@angular/material/stepper";
import {MatDatepickerModule} from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {MatDividerModule} from "@angular/material/divider";
import {MatExpansionModule} from "@angular/material/expansion";
import {MatGridListModule} from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatListModule} from "@angular/material/list";
import {MatMenuModule} from "@angular/material/menu";
import {MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatProgressBarModule} from "@angular/material/progress-bar";
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import {MatRadioModule} from "@angular/material/radio";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatSidenavModule} from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import {MatSliderModule} from "@angular/material/slider";
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from "@angular/material/slide-toggle";
import {MatSnackBarModule} from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import {MatTabsModule} from "@angular/material/tabs";
import {MatToolbarModule} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatTooltipModule} from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {provideHttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app/app.component";
import {appConfig} from "./app/app.config";
import {UserListComponent} from "./app/user-list/user-list.component";
import {CarListComponent} from "./app/cars-list/car-list.component";
import {CarComponent} from "./app/car/car.component";
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import {MatSortModule} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {UserCarsComponent} from "./app/user-cars/user-cars.component";
import {UserComponent} from "./app/user/user.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {NavbarComponent} from "./app/navbar/navbar.component";

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSortModule
  ]
})
export class DemoMaterialModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [UserListComponent, UserComponent, CarListComponent, CarComponent, UserCarsComponent, NavbarComponent],
  bootstrap: [],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent

  ],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
export class AppModule {}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

navbar.component.html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Cars App</a>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleNavbar()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav nav-underline" [class.show]="isNavbarOpen" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/users">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/cars">Cars</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-toolbar>

navbar.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  isNavbarOpen = false;
  toggleNavbar() {
    this.isNavbarOpen = !this.isNavbarOpen;
  }
}

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import { AppModule } from '../main';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppModule, RouterOutlet]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'webapp';
}

UPDATE:
When I made NavbarComponent standalone and made adjustments to wire it.
navbar.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatToolbar} from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import {MatIcon} from "@angular/material/icon";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
  standalone: true,

  imports: [
    MatToolbar,
    MatIcon
  ]
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  isNavbarOpen = false;
  toggleNavbar() {
    this.isNavbarOpen = !this.isNavbarOpen;
  }
}

It compiles but the browser has the same error

Code:
https://github.com/mr-olufsen/webapp
UPDATE 2:
The solution where NavbarComponent is integrated and rendered correct is here. Code. Although the table sorting is not working at the moment

is your application modular or standalone?

No, I use not standalone approach

The App was converted to standalone. Below were the steps followed.
Created App Module and bootstrapped it
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserComponent,
    CarListComponent,
    CarComponent,
    UserCarsComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
export class AppModule {}


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  ngZoneEventCoalescing: true
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Removed all standalone components and added them to the app component (to have a general style across the app (modular) ).
Github Repo

Only environment providers should be added inside the second argument of bootstrap application.
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, { providers: [provideHttpClient(), provideRouter(routes), ] })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Then just import the modules into the standalone components, for the component to use them, just note: Only exported members can be used in the component.
First we can convert navbar to standalone.
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
  standalone: true,

})
export class NavbarComponent {
  isNavbarOpen = false;
  toggleNavbar() {
    this.isNavbarOpen = !this.isNavbarOpen;
  }
}

Then use it in app component.
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import {NavbarComponent} from './src/navbar';
import { AppModule } from '../main';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AppModule, RouterOutlet, NavbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'webapp';
}

When working with standalone the below modules are not needed.
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes),


Thank you. My other components are not standalone. I want to be consistent and make NavbarComponent the same way. How to wire it?

I'm trying to understand how to make AppComponent non standalone

@J.Olufsen do you want standalone or modular? for the entire application, because originally you said standalone

I want to have quickest way to 1. add navbar 2. if possible to fully switch to non standalone approach, to be consistent, because I already have most of functionality working that way. For example all wiring in root main.ts file is done using not standalone way

I managed to add Navbar but unfortunately the sorting stopped working. What might be the issue?  https://github.com/mr-olufsen/webapp/commit/77174b360791c50e94bdd5de2f1e9ee0de254f94

@J.Olufsen updated my answer, as you asked your app is fully modular now!
